# How to make a string be read even if there's a text before or after a word?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a script that shows a hidden button by default whenever the user input a specific word in the textarea. In this scenario it's "Word 1", "Word 2", "Word 3", and "Word 4".

The problem I'm encountering is, why does this script now work if the user input any text before a word, even just a single space?

Please take a look at my code:

```js
$("#textarea3").on('keyup', function() {

if ($(this).val().indexOf("Word 1") === 0) {
$('#word1').css('display', 'block');
}else {
$('#word1').css('display', 'none');
}


if ($(this).val().indexOf("Word 2") === 0) {
$('#word2').css('display', 'block');
}else {
$('#word2').css('display', 'none');
}

if ($(this).val().indexOf("Word 3") === 0) {
$('#word3').css('display', 'block');
}else {
$('#word3').css('display', 'none');
}

if ($(this).val().indexOf("Word 4") === 0) {
$('#word4').css('display', 'block');
}else {
$('#word4').css('display', 'none');
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="form-control" id="textarea3" spellcheck="true" rows="4">Word</textarea>

<button id="word1" style="display:none">Word 1</button>

<button id="word2" style="display:none">Word 2</button>

<button id="word3" style="display:none">Word 3</button>

<button id="word4" style="display:none">Word 4</button>
```

I'm not sure what's preventing the textarea to read it if there's a text before the specified words..

Thank you in advance, would really appreciate it!

Comment: If by "not work", you mean that the `if` condition is resolving to false, the reason would be that you are comparing the string index to 0. If you just want to check that "Word 1" is contained in the text, use `input.indexOf('Word 1") != -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "not work", you mean that the if condition is resolving to false, the reason would be that you are comparing the string index to 0. If you just want to check that "Word 1" is contained in the text, use input.indexOf('Word 1") != -1

```
$("#textarea3").on('keyup', function() {

if ($(this).val().indexOf("Word 1") !== -1) {
$('#word1').css('display', 'block');
}else {
$('#word1').css('display', 'none');
}


if ($(this).val().indexOf("Word 2") !== -1) {
$('#word2').css('display', 'block');
}else {
$('#word2').css('display', 'none');
}

if ($(this).val().indexOf("Word 3") !== -1) {
$('#word3').css('display', 'block');
}else {
$('#word3').css('display', 'none');
}

if ($(this).val().indexOf("Word 4") !== -1) {
$('#word4').css('display', 'block');
}else {
$('#word4').css('display', 'none');
}

});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for trying to help me sir, however, it seems that the code you provided above is creating lots of bugs now. It now shows every button even if there's nothing typed. Also, it tends to now require an extra space or some text before a word, if there's none, it won't show a button.

Comment: @ixcode I hadn't changed the 0's to -1's sorry. I have no corrected my answer

Comment: It's ok, it works fine now after doing that! Thank you for giving me this solution, It really helps me understand it now!